# convergence warning:Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (200) reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter

This is an exercise for using `ANN`.

I now applying `MLPClassifier` on training sets below.

```
D1= {D1+={(6,2), (6,-2), (12,2), (12,-2)}, D1-={(2,0), (0,-2), (0,2), (-2,0)}}

D2= {D2+={(4,2), (4,-2), (-4,2), (-4,-2)}, D2-={(2,1), (2,-1), (-2,1), (-2,-1)}}
```

And using the codes below:

```
x = [[6,-2],[6,2],[12,-2],[12,2],[2,0],[0,-2],[0,2],[-2,0]]

y = [1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1]

from sklearn import neural_network
clf = neural_network.MLPClassifier(solver='adam',alpha=0.0001,hidden_layer_sizes=(5,2), random_state=1, batch_size='auto')

clf.fit(x,y)

predicted = clf.predict([[0,0],[8,3]])

print(predicted)
```

Try to change the classifier but failed cause of the errors below:

> c:\users\asuspc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py:564: ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (200) reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet.
>         % self.max_iter, ConvergenceWarning)

What should I do?

Comment: Thats not an error. Just a warning about not converging in the given iterations. You can try increasing the iterations by setting `max_iter` to a higher value.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by setting max_iter=2000, it takes a while longer to process but renders a better graph takes care of the warning in PyCharm.